# WordPress Admin Toolbar Disappeared when moved site to subfolder

Tags: wp-admin

I followed the good direction from the WordPress site of having WordPress installed in a sub folder and having the url showing without the subfolder showing.

Now when I login, it redirects to the subfolder and login no problem, then when I view the site when logged in I dont get the Admin Toolbar at the top of the site?

Any suggestions on what to do, is it a cookie issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well looks like the solution was I logged out of the admin / my account. I then went to another browser which I have not used to log into the website with before and logged in and now the admin/toolbar appears when browsing the website.

Little bit embarrassing to how long I spend on this, one of those moments.

Anyway hope it may help someone else.